# LinkedIn API not working, returning Error: HTTP GET - The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone

Tags: sharepoint, linkedin-api

We have been using LinkedIn API to access to the feeds from LinkedIn since last 2 years.

But suddenly this API has stopped working and returns below error code.

> `Error: HTTP GET - The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.`

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate to V2 API.

Find details here:

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

and here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq